# Minkowski's theorem for non-symmetric convex bodies

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Minkowski's theorem for convex bodies states that every convex, symmetric subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ whose volume is larger than $2^d$ contains a non-zero integer point. All the proofs I've seen rely on the symmetric part of it but it seems intuitive that it could be dropped. Are there any results or counterexamples on this?

EDIT: as was pointed out below, if $0$ is not an element of the subset then we can construct a counterexample but what if $0$ is in the set?

Comment: "Lectures on the Geometry of Numbers" by Carl Ludwig Siegel might be a useful reference, no mention of symmetric in the formulation of the theorem.

Comment: For future reference, Siegel's formulations of Minkowski's theorems do use symmetry.  Instead of the word symmetric, he uses the phrases "convex body with centre (at the origin)" or "convex body with even gauge function", which are equivalent to the symmetry condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the rectangle with vertices at $(-5000,.1),(-5000,.9),(5000,.1),(5000,.9)$. It is a convex subset of ${\bf R}^2$ with volume $8000>2^2$ and no lattice point at all.

Comment: Ah, of course. The centring of the set is simply to ensure that every direction has some lattice point. How about if we insist that the set contains $0$? That would exclude these translates.

Comment: Take a triangle with vertices at $(-\epsilon,-\delta),(1-\gamma,-\delta),(1-\gamma,y)$, where the greek letters are small positive reals, and $y$ is large. I'm sure you can finagle things so the are no lattice points, other than the origin, but the area is (roughly) $y/2$.

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks.